# How to change null and empty string in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

Here is my sqlite databse ,you can see some cell are null or  empty string when opening with sqlitemanager.

How can i change all the null and empty string into 0 (zero) in this sqlite database ,not by hand one by one (you can do it in sqlite manager,but it is stupid to change all in one database).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE grade SET d3 = 0
   WHERE d3 IS NULL OR d3 = ''
```